# Jira - Re-order subtasks in Backlog View

Tags: jira

Is it possible to change the order of the subtasks as they are shown in the backlog view, so that it matches the order shown in the story view?

For example, when editing a story, I can sort the subtasks here and change their order:
[image]

But in the backlog view, the order is unchanged:
[image]

Is it possible to make the backlog view order match the order shown when viewing the task?

Answer (score 0):

JIRA uses the Rank field to determine the relative order of tickets when they are listed on a board. I am no sure if Scrum board backlogs use this same Rank field.

Even if they did use that, I don't think the "sorting" you can do on sub-tasks uses the Rank field. Sorry I don't think this is possible here.

If you were using Portfolio 2.0, and ranking your sub-tasks in the tree hierarchy there I do think it will keep the actual rank syncd in JIRA.